# Access Google Chrome Inspect Element with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

I have a problem and I can't quite find the solution.
My task is to access the text provided from Google Chrome Inspect Element.
For example - if I would be given a webpage "http://stackoverflow.com" then I should get the text located in Inspect Element (right click->Inspect element).
Does anyone know how to do this in .NET?

P.S. I have an alternative solution, but I want to maximize the effectiveness of this task. My current solution is making .NET to open Google Chrome programmatically and then with keyboard shortcuts access the Inspect Element text.
But I would like to do this in background(the programm does everything while I'm doing some other stuff).

Comment: Suppose there is an efficient way to do this w/o keyboard shortcuts. Your 'task' says you can't use that?

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose of your task?  Do you really need the exact text from Inspect Element, or are you really just pulling out DOM properties?  In the second case you may as well use IE query the DOM directly.

Comment: To be specific - the webpage contains a media file. But in the page source you can't see the link to it. But in the Inspect Element you can. This why I need to access Inspect Element throw .NET

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to download the page source? Because that is basically what inspect element does. Please tell me if i'm wrong.

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
            string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
            // Create a new WebClient instance.
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
            myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
            // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);     
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
            Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);
```

Not my code, it's from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2.

Then you can use whatever function to read the file and use the source.

Comment: No. I know how to download the page source the thing is that the page source is not equivalent to the Inspect element.

Comment: To be specific - the webpage contains a media file. But in the page source you can't see the link to it. But in the Inspect Element you can. This why I need to access Inspect Element throw .NET

Comment: Dont solution for use inspect by c#?